# SVG foreignObject not showing inside angular template

Tags: angular, svg

I use inline SVG in an Angular9 component template. I want to display a HTML element inside this SVG. When I try to use SVG foreignObject in it, it is not displayed.

```
<p>Inline SVG with foreignobject inside angular component:</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="100px">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="yellow"/>
  <foreignobject  x="10" y="10" width="100px" height="50px" >
    <xhtml:div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background-color: aqua;">
      foreign object
    </xhtml:div> 
  </foreignobject> 
</svg>
```

When I use same SVG code elsewhere, it is working. For example, when I insert following code directly in index.html (not in angular component), it displays correctly:

```
<p>SVG with foreignobject in index.html (not in angular component):</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="100px">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="yellow"/>
  <foreignobject  x="10" y="10" width="100px" height="50px" >
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background-color: aqua;">
      foreign object
    </div> 
  </svg:foreignobject> 
</svg>
```

I am missing something, or is it an bug inside Angular? See example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frdbxq

Comment: If your mime type is xhtml then foreignobject is incorrect, and should be foreignObject. If your mime type is html then xthml:div is incorrect and should be div. So either way something needs fixing.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you, it was just character case... Now it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of Angular template you should pay attention on the case-sensive way of writing tags:

```
<foreignobject 
        ||
        \/
<foreignObject
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mh4ycr?file=src/app/app.component.html)**